# regex - Unable to use regex variable in conditional statement (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have created a regex as a variable, however when I call that variable in a conditional statement to test the regex, if fails.

Below is my code:

```
var str = "SERR PBQR PNZC!";

var newStr = [];

var pattern = new RegExp('^[A-Z0-9!@#$%^&*)(+=._-]+$', 'i'); // corrected

/*
Matches first 13 and then last 13 charcters of alphabet and adds 13 to 
Unicode character and remove 13 respectively. Final Unicode values get added 
to array. If the character is not part of alphabet, character remains as is 
and is also pushed to array.
*/
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i].match(/^[A-M]*$/)) {
      newStr.push(str.charCodeAt(i) + 13);
  } else if (str[i].match(/^[N-Z]*$/)) {
      newStr.push(str.charCodeAt(i) - 13);
  } else {
      newStr.push(str[i]);
  }

/*
If statement used for special character validation as defined by regex 
pattern variable. Special characters are ignored and pushed to newWord 
array, Unicode characters mapped back to alphabet and pushed to newWord 
array.
*/
var newWord = newStr.map(function (val) {
  if (val == pattern) {
      return val;
  } else {
      return String.fromCharCode(val);
  }
});

}

console.log(newWord);

//["F", "R", "E", "E", " ", "C", "O", "D", "E", " ", "C", "A", "M", "P", " "]
```

The above outputs all words in an array and accounts for whitespaces, it however also changes my "!" to a whitespace as well (this is why I am attempting validation in my array.map).

I know the validation works because when I manually enter in a "!", it checks out. Could anyone explain where I am going wrong with using the regex here? Nothing I have found online seems to have worked for me.

P.S I have also tried "/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*)(+=._-]+$/g" as well as "/!/" which didn't work.

Comment: You're using the `RegExp` constructor instead of the regex literal syntax, but not escaping the backslashes in the string that you pass to the `RegExp` constructor.

Comment: `pattern` is a regex object, can you compare that to an array ?

Comment: Read the docs more closely, especially about the `RegExp` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this one sorted. The problem was 2 fold, 1) the regex was not correctly defined, 2) the regex was being used directly on the elements of an array and can only be used on a string (of which I was not aware until now).

Code fix is below:

```
var str = "SERR PBQR PNZC!";

var newStr = [];

var pattern = new RegExp(/^[^\w]$/, 'i'); // corrected

//Matches alphabetical characters (A-M and N-Z) and converts to unicode to 
add/remove 13 from value.
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i].match(/^[A-M]*$/)) {
      newStr.push(str.charCodeAt(i) + 13);
  } else if (str[i].match(/^[N-Z]*$/)) {
      newStr.push(str.charCodeAt(i) - 13);
  } else {
      newStr.push(str[i]);
  }

 // If statement used for special character validation and to convert 
unicode to alphabet.
var newWord = newStr.map(function (val) {
  if (val.toString().match(pattern)) {  // corrected
      return val;
  } else {
      return String.fromCharCode(val);
  }
});

}

console.log(newWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

`var pattern = new RegExp("/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g");`

The way to define a regex object with the RegExp constructor is either: (with a string)

```
var pattern = new RegExp('^[A-Z0-9!@#$%^&*)(+=._-]+$', 'i');
```

or (with a literal pattern)

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/^[A-Z0-9!@#$%^&*)(+=._-]+$/i);
```

You can also simply write:

```
var pattern = /^[A-Z0-9!@#$%^&*)(+=._-]+$/i;
```

Using the g flag with a pattern anchored with `^` and `$` is useless.

Note also that you don't have to escape special characters inside a character class.

What you are trying to do with `if (val == pattern) {` isn't clear at all.

---

I think what you are trying to do is:

```
var str = "SERR PBQR PNZC!";

// validation: test if the string contains only allowed characters

if ( /^[A-Z0-9!@#$%^&*)(+=._ -]+$/i.test(str) ) {

    // translation:
    var newstr = str.replace(/([a-m])|[n-z]/gi, function (m,g) {
        return String.fromCharCode(m.charCodeAt(0) + ( g ? 13 : -13 ));
    }, str);

    console.log(newstr);
}
```

Comment: Comments added to code. What I am attempting with `if (val == pattern) {` is to check whether the array I am mapping contains a special character (in this case "!"), if it does, it returns that value without being changed. If the element is not a special character then it converts it back to the alphabetical value represented by the Unicode character. If i manually enter "!" in the If condition `if (val == "!") {` , it works, however the place holder variable for the regex pattern does not. This is my exact problem. I have tried your regex fixes (string and literal), it still does not resolve

Answer (score -1):

You are using `.match` which returns an array or null. If you want to use a regex in a conditional, you need to use `.test` which returns a Boolean. Read more about JS regex [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Working_with_regular_expressions).